# Relative Layout Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have  a relative layout which consists a `Button` a `EditText`

At the time of page loading I am initializing the relative layout like this

```
RelativeLayout bottomLayout;
bottomLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.s_r_l_bottom);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
     (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) bottomLayout .getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1);
bottomLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams );
```

As a result my relative layout was at the bottom of the screen.
Now what I am trying that  I also have  `Button` on the top the screen .

By pressing the button I want that the relative layout will be on the center of the screen

For that I have used the following code on button click(The code is executing.I have tested that).But it did not help me.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) bottomLayout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, -1);
bottomLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Can you please help me out to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you dont' have two rules at the same time: bottom and center one, after pressing the button? Therefore they confuse each other...

Comment: I want that when I click the button the layout will come to center from bottom.

Comment: Try cancel the bottom align first, perhaps with addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);

Comment: before adding the new rule, you should `removeRule()` the bottom rule.